# VOD Ad Replacement using AWS MediaTailor

Tags: amazon-web-services, vast, aws-elemental, vod, aws-mediatailor

Is it possible to replace a HLS segment with an AD in VOD playout?

For example, if I've a HLS playlist below, I want to replace 360p_002.ts with an VAST AD if available, if not include 360p_002.ts in the Playout. Is this an option?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:20
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXTINF:20.020000,
360p_000.ts
#EXTINF:20.020000,
360p_001.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-OUT:0
360p_002.ts
#EXT-X-CUE-IN
#EXTINF:20.020000,
360p_003.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elemental MediaTailor is a service which manipulates/decorates the manifest by inserting segments for advertisements when it encounters SCTE Markers. It does not remove existing segments. Therefore, it is not possible to delete a segment or segments using the AWS Elemental MediaTailor service. For features of AWS Elemental MediaTailor refer the guide[1]

=======Documentation=========

[1]https://aws.amazon.com/mediatailor/features/